# GetOpenFileName open at default directory 'Computer' possible?

Tags: c++, winapi, getopenfilename

I'm using `GetOpenFileName` to open files in C++, is it possible to set the initial dir at "Computer" virtual location with `lpstrInitialDir`?

Thanks,
Lee.

Comment: Have you tried? If not: Why not?

Comment: In Windows 7 if you have changed current directory in open or save dialog boxes and lpstrInitialDir it is the same as well as the first lpstrInitialDir used by the program when calling first time Open or Save dialogs then the last "current directory" it is used instead of that specified in lpstrInitialDir https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms646839(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have tried "Computer"   that doesn't work as it's not valid.

Comment: I have tried:-
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(
NULL,
lpszPath,
CSIDL_DRIVES,
false
);

with lpszPath    and this blank.

Comment: You cannot fetch its path as it has no path `CSILD_DRIVES/FOLDERID_ComputerFolder` is documented as *Default Path: Not applicable—virtual folder*

Comment: so you think it's not possible to start the file dialog up under "Computer" ?

Comment: @user3725395 - begin from vista you can use `IFileDialog` and set initial folder by `IFileDialog::SetFolder` : `SHGetKnownFolderIDList(FOLDERID_ComputerFolder)`->`SHCreateItemFromIDList`->`SetFolder`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with `GetOpenFileName` because the location you wish to use is not part of the file system. Rather it is part of the wider shell namespace.

If you look at the documentation for `GetOpenFileName` you will see that it has been superseded (over 10 years ago in fact) by the Common Item Dialogs. Those dialogs do allow you to specify the initial folder as a shell item.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to support legacy Windows older than Vista, where `IFileDialog` is not available, try specifying a Shell folder GUID. For example, the `My Computer` GUID is `20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D`. You can specify it like this:

```
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}";
```

However, it is worth noting that this method is almost doomed to fail on Windows 7 and later, due to [behavioral changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646839.aspx)

So, you are better off using `IFileDialog` on Vista and later instead.